# Database initialization failed

Tags: mysql, database-connection

hMailServer installation in windows 2003 (x64) encountered an error as `Database initialization failed`. I created a database and new user for that database in Plesk's MySQL database engine. Finally hMailServer asked to copy libmysql.dll file present in bin folder of MySQL to Bin folder of hMailServer installation path. I did it correctly then when I click on retry I am getting this error. I googled for this and found no relevant result and no specific response from hMailServer's forums for previous posts. Can anybody tell me why this error occurred?

Comment: I think this question should be done in hMailServer forums / mailing list as it's not a programming question, it's a help desk question.

Comment: @Augusto - There is no response from hMailServer forums :-(